# Can you scroll the background image of a form?

Tags: forms, scroll, background-image

Can anyone please have a look at this example and tell me why the background image is not scrolling? I'm talking about the blue lines in the main field below "Email". If you overflow it with text, you get a vertical scrollbar, but when you scroll, the background image (the blue lines) do not. Fiddling with background-attachment doesn't help.

I have seen questions (and answers) about this problem in divs but not in form fields.

http://www.eyalmyrthe.nl/contactform.htm

Thanks a lot!